# How many number between 5000 and 10,000 with no repeated digits and no 0 digits?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many numbers between 5000 and 10,000 can be formed using the digits 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, each digit appearing not more than once in each number?

the solution to this problem is given as 5*P(8,3) but I don't understand how,
the way I do this question is that there are four places to be filled and first one has 5 options from (5,6,7,8,9) and then we have 8 options for next place, 7, for next and 6 for last, so total number of numbers that can be formed = 5*8*7*6, I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: How are you defining $P(8,3)$?

Comment: Did you check if your way and their way yield the same numerical result? There are many ways of solving a problem.

Comment: P(8,3) is C(8,3)\*3! and C(8,3) is combination of three to be chosen from 8 objects.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think it means exclusive, but it does not matter

Comment: your answer and the given answer are equal @ManuSm

Comment: @CalvinLin I just rechecked my method is giving same answer as the one given in textbook, I got confused so committed a calculation mistake, thanks though

Comment: @DS yes figured that out, thanks for pointing out though

Comment: Exotic symbols like P(8,3) or C(8,3) are not intuitive. They generate only troubles. As soon as you replace those symbols by their simple value, the answer is clear. Formulas should always be written with symbols that every one can understand (my children who are 12 years old, or my butcher)

Answer (score 1):

Just divide the problem, or else it will create bigger problem

You pointed out correctly that there are 4 places, and first one will either be 5,6,7,8,9.

Now if the first place is 5, then we have

- first gap: 1
- second gap: 8
- third gap: 7
- fourth gap: 6

The first place is 5, so only 1 way of choosing it. The next place maybe 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9 (5 can't be repeated) so 8 options. Now the 3rd gap will be 7 and then 4th gap 6.
So this is basically choosing 3 numbers from 8 numbers as 1st gap is already 5.
So we may write this as P(8,3) i.e permutation of 8 objects taken 3 at a time.

The same process will be repeated when the first place is either 6,7,8 or 9
So the first gap maybe filled in 5 ways (5,6,7,8,9)
So final result is 5*P(3,8) which your solution has told you.

But you are doing absolutely correct. Some say water some say H2O. Just the same. You are perfect.

Comment: please don't use all caps, some people may find it rude

Comment: @DS thanks for the suggestion. I have made suitable edits.